# Pagination in Magento widget block

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi is there any way to do pagination in widget block . For example  have a category with id 355 . I want to display that category product in a page . So i am using widget( following code )

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="160" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`355`^]^]"}}
```

. But there are upto 155 product in that category the product are displaying in the page  . But for 155 product the page load time is too high . So if there will be pagination for that then its easy to load the products .

Comment: can you specify the exact version of your Magento2 ?

Comment: I have added an update to my ansewer, could you check if it resolves your issue with pagination ?

Comment: any updates ....

Comment: thank you . It is working now

Comment: Great to hear that :) you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact **Yes**, pager is implemented for Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList, you just need to activate it using **show_pager="1"** and define how much products to show per page **products_per_page="6"** (if you ignore this param then default value is 5)

**UPDATE :** 
I guess you need to add the param **page_var_name="np"** where 'np' is the name of the pagination parameter (you can name it at your convenience), like following and this should resolve the pagination issue :

Your code shoud be like this :

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="1" products_per_page="6" products_count="160" page_var_name="np" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`355`^]^]"}}
```

@see : *vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php*

```
class ProductsList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements BlockInterface, IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Name of request parameter for page number value
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    const PAGE_VAR_NAME = 'np';

    /**
     * Default value for products per page
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE = 5;

    /**
     * Default value whether show pager or not
     */
    const DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER = false;
...


   /**
     * Retrieve how many products should be displayed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsPerPage()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('products_per_page')) {
            $this->setData('products_per_page', self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE);
        }
        return $this->getData('products_per_page');
    }

    /**
     * Return flag whether pager need to be shown or not
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showPager()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('show_pager')) {
            $this->setData('show_pager', self::DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER);
        }
        return (bool)$this->getData('show_pager');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how many products should be displayed on page
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getPageSize()
    {
        return $this->showPager() ? $this->getProductsPerPage() : $this->getProductsCount();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i change the code and now pagination is showing . But the problem  is that same products are showing in every page . Is there is any solution ? . I have cleared all cache and check it . Again same result

Comment: Can you confirm that your category contains 155 different products which are all **enabled** and **visible**

Comment: yes all products are enable and visible . When i am not using pagination then i can see all products in that page, but when i use pagination and i click in page numbers , in every page same product is showing

Comment: can you specify the exact version of your Magento2 ?